# Using tail command to create a file

Tags: bash, tail

This is what I did using `tail` command. When I try to output the file to screen the file is empty.

```
~]$ tail > AFS2F1
PASSES ALL DATA FROM INPUT TO OUTPUT
PASSES ONLY SPECIFIED COLUMNS
PASSES NUMBER OF SPECIFIED LINES AT BEGINNING
COMBINES COLUMNS
ARRANGES DATA IN SEQUENCE
PASSES NUMBER OF SPECIFIED LINES AT THE END OF DATA
TRANSLATES ONE OR MORE CHARACTERS
DELETES DUPLICATE LINES
COUNTS CHARACTERS, WORDS, OR LINES
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Is there anything wrong with the way I'm using tail command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tail` will only output the last 10 lines. So one way or another, you'll have to tell it you've finished typing so it knows what lines (the 10 last ones) to output.

If you press <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> (the default `intr` character on most systems) a SIGINT signal will be sent to it which will kill it. Because it had not seen the end of input by the time you killed it, it will not have had the opportunity to write anything yet, so it will die without having output anything.

The *terminal* way to signify the end of input (when the terminal is in *canonical* mode) is to enter the `eof` character (by default <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> on most systems)  on an empty line.

Then `tail` will detect that the end of input is being reached and will output the 10 last lines that it has received.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should provides a input to `tail`, so :

```
tail file > newfile
```

If you want to use STDIN :

```
cat file | tail > newfile
```

or

```
 head > new_file < file
```

or

```
tail > AFS2F1<<EOF
PASSES ALL DATA FROM INPUT TO OUTPUT
PASSES ONLY SPECIFIED COLUMNS
PASSES NUMBER OF SPECIFIED LINES AT BEGINNING
COMBINES COLUMNS
ARRANGES DATA IN SEQUENCE
PASSES NUMBER OF SPECIFIED LINES AT THE END OF DATA
TRANSLATES ONE OR MORE CHARACTERS
DELETES DUPLICATE LINES
COUNTS CHARACTERS, WORDS, OR LINES
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
EOF
```

Comment: Then how do i use tail to create a file from stdin? The way I did above was similar for cat command so i thought i would work

Comment: `tail > file` is perfectly fine if the user wants to type a bunch of stuff on stdin and save the last 10 lines into the file.

Comment: See my edited post

Comment: Thou shalt not use `cat(1)` in vain.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `tail` program buffers its input file until it get a `eof` condition, then it prints out the last lines (10 by default). Most likely you are interrupting it with `ctrl-c` combination that terminates it, thus the tail has no chance to print out the collected lines. If you use `ctrl-d` instead then you effectively send the `end-of-file` character to the tail's input stream, so it will print out the lines collected.